# right_now_content_table_end function not working?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, widgets, dashboard, count

I noticed recently my custom counts for custom post types are not showing on the dashboard. Im using this function:

[right_now_content_table_end](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/right_now_content_table_end)

It worked well before, Im not sure when it stopped working but I think after updating to 3.8?

Or is there a new function I should use with the new dashboard that is in 3.8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The new action is `dashboard_glance_items`. It is a filter providing an array to which you can add items.

Example from my plugin [T5 Taxonomy Location](https://github.com/toscho/t5-taxonomy-location)

```
add_filter(
    'dashboard_glance_items',
    array ( $this, 'add_to_glance' )
);


/**
 * Add locations to the new "At a glance" dashboard widget.
 *
 * @param  array $items
 * @return array
 */
public function add_to_glance( Array $items )
{
    $num  = wp_count_terms( $this->taxonomy );
    // Singular or Plural.
    $text = _n(
        '%s Location',
        '%s Locations',
        $num,
        'plugin_t5_tax_location'
    );
    // thousands separator etc.
    $text = sprintf( $text, number_format_i18n( $num ) );

    if ( current_user_can( "manage_$this->taxonomy" ) )
    {
        $url  = admin_url( "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=$this->taxonomy" );
        $text = "<a href='$url'>$text</a>";
    }

    $items[] = $text;

    return $items;
}
```

This change is not backwards compatible and rather … dirty. See ticket [#26571](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26571) for problems and possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, I checked but there is no codex reference created for this yet. Because I want to use it in a theme.

Answer (score 0):

The new thing is essentially different widget and that hook was removed from core. The closest replacement is new `dashboard_glance_items` filter.

See trac tickets:

- [#26495 (Dashboard "At a Glance" hooks changed)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26495)
- [#26571 (Increase flexibility of "At a Glance" Dashboard Widget to match "Right Now" Widget)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26571)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this function. I believe it's temporary solution, but it works for me. More info can be found here: [Add Custom Post Types and Taxonomies to At a Glance dashboard widget](http://creative-pad.com/wordpress/add-custom-post-types-taxonomies-glance-dashboard-widget/)

```
add_action( 'dashboard_glance_items', 'cor_right_now_content_table_end' );
function cor_right_now_content_table_end() {
$args = array(
    'public' => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);
$output = 'object';
$operator = 'and';

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $post_type->name );
    $num = number_format_i18n( $num_posts->publish );
    $text = _n( $post_type->labels->singular_name, $post_type->labels->name, intval( $num_posts->publish ) );
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        $output = '<a href="edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type->name . '">' . $num . '&nbsp;' . $text . '</a>';
    }
    echo '<li class="post-count ' . $post_type->name . '-count">' . $output . '</li>';
}
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator );
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    $num_terms = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy->name );
    $num = number_format_i18n( $num_terms );
    $text = _n( $taxonomy->labels->singular_name, $taxonomy->labels->name, intval( $num_terms ) );
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_categories' ) ) {
        $output = '<a href="edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $taxonomy->name . '">' . $num . '&nbsp;' . $text . '</a>';
    }
    echo '<li class="taxonomy-count ' . $taxonomy->name . '-count">' . $output . '</li>';
}
}

// Add Some CSS to "At a Glance" Widget
function custom_colors() {
echo '<style type="text/css">
    .slides-count a:before {content:"\f233"!important}
    .gallery-count a:before {content:"\f163"!important}
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_colors');
```

Comment: And what happens when a post type/taxonomy plugin adds its own items already?

Comment: @toscho What do you mean?

Comment: @RichardMišenčík My custom taxonomy would be listed twice.

Comment: Well, i never said that it's all-in-one solution. It works perfectly on one of my websites which has 3 CPT and 4 taxonomies.

Comment: You can easily extend it by adding simple option page and manually select what CPT or taxonomy you want to be displayed there. Also it's going to be much easier to choose a custom icon from a predefined list.

Comment: @ViktorKovalenko One thing Im wondering is, why if the current user is not admin, the $output then is just the text 'object'?